# When do a Regular graph has an odd eigenvalue?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Merely looking at adjacency matrix of a *regular* graph, without explicit calculation, can we decide that graph will have an odd eigenvalue or not?

If *regularity* is odd, we are sure that it will be an odd e.v for graph but when regularity is not odd, what does a graph suggest by an odd e.v.?

Does having odd e.v. has something to do with structure of graph?

Any help or reference is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an 'odd' eigenvalue? Do you mean that its multiplicity is an odd number or that the e.v. itself is an odd number?

Comment: Eigenvalue itself is an odd number.

Comment: Sorry if this is more of a question than an answer but do you know of any implication of the adjacency matrix having integer eigenvalues (other than the regularity constant)? I ask because in general most eigenvalues are not even integers which makes your question somewhat baffling to me :)

Comment: Do you know Hadamard diagonalizable graphs? They are regular and have integer eigenvalues. (further all these e.v are even). In general I don't know is there something hidden in the structure of regular integral graphs ...Definitely i would love to know that.

Comment: Just a fun fact: If we consider the cycle graph $C_n$ on $n$ vertices, then it has regularity $2$, i.e. the e.v.s of its adjacency matrix are in $[-2,2]$. Computing the first 20 or so, it seems that $-1$ is an ev of $C_n$ if and only if $n = 3m$. Furthermore, $1$ is an ev of $C_n$ if and only if $n = 6m$.

Comment: Looking at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegralGraph.html , it seems that integral graphs tend to be quite symmetric. Maybe there is a connection between being an integral graph and having a large automorphism group...

Comment: A graph having a large automorphism group means?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23985/discussion-between-sry-and-genericnickname).